# VS Code Terminal Cursor: Exit Vim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I must have pressed or selected some button to trigger this. I have used Node REPL, cd,mk etc,npm as well as git commands recently and can switch back to root directory in terminal easily. However now when I type any character it switches into a mode that looks like Vim. What is this? And how to switch back to normal C:\bla\blah\bla\root to do my normal git or npm or cd commands again? Also it seems like an never ending loop that when I hit Enter it goes out of it but then any keyboard character brings me back.

Appears I am in Vim and 'q' does quit but then any typing throws me back in vim. **I don't have any vim extensions installed or anything**.

Issue is show below where number 2 is the normal screen I need to revert to and 1 is screen that I keep getting thrown into. Also highlighted the bar below to show settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:` key starts the `vim ex command line`. You can press escape to exit it.

Comment: Maybe I hit that by mistake a few times then... ;-(

Answer (score 0):

1. Changed end of line sequence to CRLF and UTF8.
2. Restarted VS Code a few times and it cleared and stopped the Vim command line.
3. If it starts again then the normal `vim` commands should be able to get you out of it. Find exit and quit commands here: https://vim.rtorr.com/